# send_Keys Attribute Error pls any Answer my question

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.9

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/")
search = driver.find_element_by_name("field-keywords")
search.send_Keys("headphone")
search.send_Keys(Keys.RETURN)
click = driver.find_element_by_id("nav-search-submit-text").click()

driver.close()
```

Error:

```
  search.send_Keys("headphone")
AttributeError:'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_Keys'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to be `send_keys`, not `send_Keys`. There is no method called `send_Keys`. Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/")
search = driver.find_element_by_name("field-keywords")
search.send_keys("headphone")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
click = driver.find_element_by_id("nav-search-submit-text").click()

driver.close()
```